# TabBar for iOS which can use images for buttons

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Are there any decent third party tab bar controllers which can use an image for a button?

Answer (score 2):

There is [a whole selection over at cocoacontrols.com](http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UITabBarController&commit=Search).